minimal verification of equilateral spherical triangles
I am calculating a large variety of equilateral triangles over a unit sphere and I want to be able to validate that any given three coordinates they are indeed what they need to be.
Google showed me lots of complicated maths which I don't understand, so I asked GPT (which is a last resort for me, due to its being unreliable).
This is what it gave me (while not understanding math notation, I do understand python):
    # Calculate the dot products
    dot12 = np.dot(v1, v2)
    dot23 = np.dot(v2, v3)
    dot31 = np.dot(v3, v1)

    # Calculate the angular distances
    theta12 = np.arccos(dot12)
    theta23 = np.arccos(dot23)
    theta31 = np.arccos(dot31)

    # Check if all angular distances are equal within a tolerance
    return np.abs(theta12 - theta23) < tolerance and \
        np.abs(theta23 - theta31) < tolerance and \
        np.abs(theta31 - theta12) < tolerance

Tolerance, above is set to $1\times10$-6 and is to deal with rounding errors of the underlying cpu. Needless to say, I would prefer to keep the rounding error as minimal as possible, which is why I think that less processing is better. Of course there may be a much more elegant and less error-prone means of identifying whether or not three vectors are a (spherical) equilateral triangle, but I do not know it!.
The stuff above makes some sort of sense to me, and it works - but I'm wondering if it's not overly redundant. When testing, I found that comparison of the three dot products gave me a good idea of if the coordinates depict an equilateral spherical triangle.
The question is - am I right?  Do I need to calculate the angular distances at all? Does the calculation of the angular distances offer a more consistent meaning to the tolerance being set? Am I missing a subtle advantage?  Does it bring more meaning to the tolerance value?

It all depends on what "tolerance" means for you.

Noted. I will correct.
